# Add data type from PostgreSQL extension in Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, postgis, slick

I'm using the PostGIS extension for PostgreSQL and I'm trying to retrieve a `PGgeometry` object from a table.

This version is working fine :

```scala
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection
import org.postgis.PGgeometry

object PostgersqlTest extends App {
  val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gis"

  var connection:Connection = null

  try {
    Class.forName(driver)
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)

    val statement = connection.createStatement()
    val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT geom FROM table;")

    while ( resultSet.next() ) {
      val geom = resultSet.getObject("geom").asInstanceOf[PGgeometry]
      println(geom)
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
  }
  connection.close()
}
```

I need to be able to do the same thing using Slick custom query. But this version doesn't work :

```scala
Q.queryNA[PGgeometry]("SELECT geom FROM table;")
```

and gives me this compilation error

```
Error:(50, 40) could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[org.postgis.PGgeometry]
  val query = Q.queryNA[PGgeometry](
                                   ^
```

Is there a simple way to add the `PGgeometry` data type in Slick without having to convert the returned object to a String and parse it?

Answer (score 0):

To use it successfully, you need define a `GetResult`, and maybe `SetParameter` if you want to insert/update it to db.

Here's some codes extracted from slick [tests](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/PlainSQLTest.scala) (p.s. I assume you're using slick 2.1.0):

```
implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => new User(r.<<, r.<<))
case class User(id:Int, name:String)

val userForID = Q[Int, User] + "select id, name from USERS where id = ?"
```

But, if your java/scala type is `jts.Geometry` instead of `PGgeometry`, you can try to use `slick-pg`, which has built-in support for `jts.Geometry` and `PostGIS` for `slick` Lifted and Plain SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the same issue, I used `slick-pg (0.8.2)`and JTS's `Geometry` classes as tminglei mentioned in the previous answer. There are two steps to use `slick-pg` to handle PostGIS's geometry types: (i) extend Slick's PostgresDriver with `PgPostGISSupport` and (ii) define an implicit converter for your plain query as shown below.

As shown in [this page](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/slick2/src/test/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/addon/PgPostGISSupportTest.scala), you should first extend the PostgresDriver with PgPostGISSupport:

```
object MyPostgresDriver extends PostgresDriver with PgPostGISSupport {

    override lazy val Implicit = new Implicits with PostGISImplicits
    override val simple = new Implicits with SimpleQL with PostGISImplicits with PostGISAssistants

    val plainImplicits = new Implicits with PostGISPlainImplicits
}
```

Using the implicit conversions defined in `plainImplicits` in the extended driver, you can write your query as:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString // Or any other JTS geometry types.
import MyPostgresDriver.plainImplicits._
import scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult

case class Row(id: Int, geom: LineString)

implicit val geomConverter = GetResult[Row](r => {
    Row(r.nextInt, r.nextGeometry[LineString])
})

val query = Q.queryNA[Row](
"""SELECT id, geom FROM table;"""
)
```